# Unreadable HDD under Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: partitioning, mount

Had a Win 7 PC I converted to Linux Ubuntu. Had problems with one program I needed on this machine (Video Surveilance) and turned back unit to Win7 - though I still have 2 Ubuntu Laptops I can work with.

The 3TB unit was a second drive, a data drive, so should not have had problems with conversion, I would think.
Since conversion, can not mount in Ubuntu and not read in Win.
Tried multiple scans etc and it seems to be holding the data, but can't read it.

---

output of DISKS

```
3TB HDD with 3 partitions, 
134MB Part-1, 2.2TB Part-2 and free space 803GB

Device /dev/sdb2
Partition Type - HPFS/NTFS
NTFS — Not Mounted
```

output of ntfs-3g

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/windows_video
$ sudo ntfs-3g -o force,rw /dev/sdb2 /media/windows
Failed to read last sector (5860268031): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the ntfs utilities with ...

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

Then do a ...

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
```

If that does not repair your disk you need to start looking for Windows tools.

Comment: You are genius!
TY - that simply worked - followed all kinds of suggestions for 3 days already.TY VM!

Comment: I do it for the rep @rfeyer ;-)